# MediaPlayer NullPointerException in local method

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-mediaplayer

My file is perfectly fine and works well on onCreate, but when I have a method call like this it is failing with `NullPointerException`

```
public void playSelectedFile() throws IOException {
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PredefinedUserPlayer.this, Uri.parse(mp3name));
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Stack trace of the error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getContentResolver(ContextWrapper.java:99)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:882)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:859)
            at lukasz.musik.PredefinedUserPlayer.playSelectedFile(PredefinedUserPlayer.java:86)
            at lukasz.musik.CustomMusicAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(CustomMusicAdapter.java:85)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

NOTE: The `url` `mp3name` is valid. It works in `onCreate` but not in `playSelectedFile()`

It keeps crashing with `NullPointerException` and `mp3name` is a valid `URL`. If the same block of code is in the `onCreate` method the compiler does not complain. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Show your full stack trace and point out the line number that matches your code sample?

Comment: Also, what exactly is the mp3name uri?

Comment: The `mp3name` uri is valid and works in `onCreate` its something like `http://XX.X.X.X/musik/musikz01.mp3` It works well in `onCreate` not the `playSelectedFile()` method. I have attached the stack trace

Comment: The compiler is not complaining. This a runtime exception.

Comment: The problem is that you have a reference that is NULL where you obviously expects it to be something else. You might want to insert some log messages in which you print out variables to see which creates the NULL pointer.

Comment: Looks like you're going to have to ask your question again and say in the text that this is not your typical NullPointerException.

Comment: I didn't initialize the `MediaPlayer` in `onCreate`. Is that needed?

Comment: No, the person who closed this incorrectly diagnosed the problem.